# how to render html cascading when using a tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My custom tag helper renders the html in one line, but I want each tag on new lines.

Tag helper:

```
switch(tag.Position)
{
    case ContentPosition.Body:
        _output.Content.AppendHtml(tag);
        break;

    case ContentPosition.PostContent:
        _output.PostContent.AppendHtml(tag);
        break;

    case ContentPosition.PostElement:
        _output.PostElement.AppendHtml(tag);
        break;

    case ContentPosition.PreContent:
        _output.PreContent.AppendHtml(tag);
        break;

    case ContentPosition.PreElement:
        _output.PreElement.AppendHtml(tag);
        break;
}
```

HTML result:

```
<script>&#xA;&#x9;&#x9;(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[&#x27;GoogleAnalyticsObject&#x27;]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){&#x9;&#x9;(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),&#x9;&#x9;m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)&#x9;&#x9;})(window,document,&#x27;script&#x27;,&#x27;https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js&#x27;,&#x27;ga&#x27;);&#xA;&#x9;&#x9;ga(&#x27;create&#x27;, &#x27;UA-146382432-6&#x27;, &#x27;auto&#x27;);&#x9;&#x9;ga(&#x27;send&#x27;, &#x27;pageview&#x27;);</script><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /><meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" /><title>Friends For UnderstandingFriends For Understanding</title><link href="/IMAGE/fav-icon.png" rel="icon" type="text/CSS" /><link href="/STYLE/Creator/Creator.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" /><link href="/STYLE/Index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" /><link href="/STYLE/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" /><link href="/STYLE/Shared.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out to add a blank line on the TagHelperContent element.

```
content.AppendLine(tag);
content.AppendBlankLine();
```